# Сложно ли создать онлайн игру?

Tags: php, html, css, разработка-игр

Сложно ли создать онлайн игру, например, Гонки?

Comment: Все зависит от технологий, желаемого результата и начальных знаний: если хотите просто 2D ездилку на <canvas> - то нет, не сложно. Попробуйте написать физику для Марио, для меня это стало хорошим уроком (хотя до логического финала я ее так и не дописал :D)

Answer (score 9):

Достаточно многое зависит от Ваших возможностей. Ведь на вопрос: "Сложно ли построить дом?" ответить однозначно нельзя. Вопрос оценивается от масштабов. Это может быть как будка, так и вила высшего класса.

Эта тема также относится к Вашему вопросу. Игры могут быть двухмерные, так и трехмерные с открытым миром и высококачественной графикой. А могут быть что-то вроде тетриса. Нельзя забывать о физике и режимах игры в "онлайн". Даже тот же онлайн, можно трактовать по разному. Можно сделать игры на время ( гонка по одному), а можно сделать режим реального времени (чтобы ездить на трассе с другими игроками). Но тут вопрос идет в сторону сети(пинг, проблемы с интернетом, все это нужно будет продумывать...)

В целом, основным фактором является уровень Ваших знаний или команды, наличия времени и желание

Answer (score 4):

Советую почитать на эту тему более подробно,тема интересная))Заодно глупые вопросы отпадут.
Я думаю сначала нужно определиться, что будет за онлайн игра. Я их подразделяю на две части, и каждой свои технологии!!!, плюс, как заметил [[@Zelta](/users/11139/zelta)](/users/11139/zelta), надо выбрать 2D || 3D):

1. Броузерные онлайн игры. Это обычно игры, типо текстовых, но есть и другие, стратегии там, и так далее. Тут преимущественно веб языки, плюс Flash, но можно и java-апплеты применить (хоть и технологии разные,возможно многие думают,что они умирают,но писать на них можно)
2. Это клиентские онлайн игры (т.е ,что-то скачивать,а потом играть). Тут господствуют C++/Java,и другие подобные игры,хотя C++,думаю тут будет лучше)

Плюс не забудьте, что в онлайне, чтобы играть нужны сервера, и подобие онлайн сервиса, у вас же будут игроки регистрироваться, значит база нужна, чтобы игра с ней соединялась, для выставления статистики и так даллее. Вот вам это на обдумывание, правильно многие советую, не пишите сразу 3D шутер, лучше напишите сначала текстовую игру консольную, а там дальше пойдет. Удачи)

Comment: >Тут господствуют C++/Java,и другие подобные игры,хотя C++

тяжелое детство - вместо игрушек Java и С++?))

Comment: хах),что-то седня руки не пишут,к "играм"тянет,наверно))

Comment: http://www.mushware.com/portal.php?page=4

Comment: КРУТО))))))

Comment: Друзья, я имею ввиду Браузерную онлайн игру на php :?: вот пример stracing.mobi

Comment: ну точ как там

Comment: > плюс Flash, но можно и java-апплеты применить

ладно еще флеш, хотя и он, мягко говоря, не лучший выбор т.к. переживает стадию загибания, но java-апплеты это однозначно не серьезно.

Comment: браузерную игру? Хм чисто на php эффектную игру не создашь ;-)

Comment: Онлайн рогалик. графика не нужна))

Answer (score 1):

Я свое время занимался созданием браузерной мобильной игры. Ушло у меня на нее полгода (было реализовано регистрация, авторизация, обучение, режим карьеры, покупка/продажа недвижимости, автомобилей, тюнинг, детали, был реализован открытый мир с возможностью встретить на дороге другого игрока (и это все в пределах wap браузерной игры), был режим драга даже, с переключением передач, но работал он откровенно плохо т.к. постоянно обновлять страницу что бы узнать когда переключать передачу, были персонажи и диалоги, гонки с ботами и чемпионаты, было достаточно много по тем меркам народу, но этим всем занимался я сам, было крайне трудно, да и это скорее хобби было, а не серьезный проект, но вот что хочу сказать, создавать легко, если у тебя есть идея, цель, знания и настрой, но в итоге это все канет в небытье в любом случае, ибо тебе надоест или ты увидишь, что это бесперспективно, по этому или работа командой или забей на это дело вообще... К слову, на проект я подзабил и с хостинга потом удалили, а исходники сгорели вместе с жестким диском, остались только воспоминания.. Вот такие дела